# if condition with AND in render attribute

Tags: visualforce

I have below following rendered attribute

```
<apex:outputLabel rendered="{!IF(AND(LastCreditCheck == '', acctObj.Decline_Credit_Check__c== false),true,false)}" />
```

Above has to be true when `acctObj.decline_Credit_Check__c` is false and LastCreditCheck value is blank.  Last CreditCheck values is given below as

```
<td >{!EquifaxRiskGrade}</td>
```

and `acctObj.decline_Credit_Check__c` is an account object field. It gives me syntax error in render attribute. 
Any help on this? 
Thanks

Comment: Protip: you can always replace `IF(condition,  true, false)` with simply `condition`.

Answer (score 1):

Fields are not generally an empty string (""), but instead are null. Regardless, if you're not sure, just use ISBLANK. Also, no need to go with the IF statement, you're just bloating your view state for no good reason.

```
rendered="{!ISBLANK(LastCreditCheck) && NOT(acctObj.Decline_Credit_Check__c)}"
```

Comment: Somehow it is not working. If i onkly use lastcredit check field it works. Somehow it is not checking the value of the checkbox it seems

Comment: @user5129806 Not sure what to tell you. There might be going on than just this simple rendered statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your rendered will look like this:

```
<apex:outputLabel 
rendered="{!(LastCreditCheck == '' && !acctObj.Decline_Credit_Check__c)}" />
```